# Submitting a form with jquery ajax and handling the response

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

In the following code I'm getting 'TypeError: response is null' in Firebug. I've tried many combinations and ways of trying to get the response but with no success. Please have a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
$("a.logmein").colorbox({ width:"540", height:"420", href:function(){ return this.href + " #login"; }, onComplete: function(){
     $("#formLoginUser").submit(function(){
         $.ajax({
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          type: "POST",
          url: $(this).attr('action'),

          success: function(response) {
            if(response.status == 'fail'){
              $("#notifications").removeClass().addClass('ajaxerror').html(response.message).show();
            } else {
              $("#notifications").removeClass().addClass('ajaxsuccess').html(response.message).show();
            }
            console.log(response);

          },
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#notifications").addClass('ajaxsuccess').html(xhr.responseText).show();
          }
        });
return false;
    });
 }});
```

ajax.php:

```
header("Content-Type:application/json"); 

    switch($_REQUEST['action']){
        case('formLoginUser'):      $afm = $_POST['afm'];
                                    $password = $_POST['password'];

                                    $query_finduser = sprintf("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE clientafm=%s and clientcode=%s and expires>%s",
                                                                   GetSQLValueString($afm, "text"),
                                                                   GetSQLValueString($password, "int"),
                                                                   GetSQLValueString(strtotime('now'), "int"));
                                    $finduser = mysql_query($query_finduser, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
                                    $row_finduser = mysql_fetch_assoc($finduser);
                                    $totalRows_finduser = mysql_num_rows($finduser); 

                                    if($totalRows_finduser==0) {
                                        echo json_encode(array("status"=>"fail", "message"=>"Login failed. Please retry"));
                                    } else {    

                                        echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success", "message"=>"Login successful!"));
                                    } 
                                    break;

    default:                    break;

}//switch end
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure the `action` attribute is properly set? (i.e. is it pointing to the right script). 2. Are you sure the script is outputting anything? (which function calls back? Is it `success`?) in which case are you just not getting into the `case('formLoginUser')` bit? You might have a problem if using `$_REQUEST` be sure not to overwrite post variables with get variables (or cookies). Similarly not all server setups allow you to use `$_REQUEST`. Is there a working example we can see?

Comment: The action is set properly, it's "includes/ajax.php?action=formLoginUser". In my ajax.php I return a json object in both cases, as you can see in my code. I used $_REQUEST with no problem before trying to make the form submit with ajax so there shouldn't be a problem there either. Unless ajax doesnt get along with $_REQUEST very well.

Comment: Hmm so it all works without ajax? Are there any javascript errors? Does the success function call back? (add `alert('called success');` to the start of the callback function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `success` callback function has 3 input parameters: `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`. What about the rest of parameters? Try to inspect them. Maybe error is in there.